# Laravel turn.js Pages not loading

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

> Problem is pages are not loading, but i loaded all css,js. I think path must be wrong.

```
---public
---------css
---------extras
---------js
---------lib
---------pages                             this is pages
---------pics
---resources
------views
---------samples
-------------magazine
------------------slider.blade.php         this is my view
```

**My JS : magazine.js**

```
img.attr('src', '/pages/' +  page + '.jpg');
$.getJSON('/pages/'+page+'-regions.json').
img.attr('src', '/pages/' +  page + '-large.jpg');
img.attr('src', '/pages/' +  page + '.jpg');
```